# PHP in Template Class

Tags: php, class, templates

I am currently working on a template class from broculus.
Now I wanted to install PHP into the template using the class. Unfortunately, I am currently failing.
By eval it is certainly not I have established. Now I wanted to ask if you have an idea how I can solve the problem easily.

Link: http://www.broculos.net/2008/03/how-to-make-simple-html-template-engine.html#.WS8jfWjyjIX

In that code I want to get the value of a variable, which is php code.
That code shall be executed.

*Example:*
`$row_1->content = '$name = 'Pagetitle'; echo $name;';`

`$row->content` contains php and complete scripts.

```
$layout = new Template("template/layout.tpl");
$layout->set("title", $sitename);
$layout->set("content", eval($row_1->content));
```

Class:

```
/**
 * Simple template engine class (use [@tag] tags in your templates).
 * 
 * @link http://www.broculos.net/ Broculos.net Programming Tutorials
 * @author Nuno Freitas <nunofreitas@gmail.com>
 * @version 1.0
 */
class Template {
    /**
     * The filename of the template to load.
     *
     * @access protected
     * @var string
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * An array of values for replacing each tag on the template (the key for each value is its corresponding tag).
     *
     * @access protected
     * @var array
     */
    protected $values = array();

    /**
     * Creates a new Template object and sets its associated file.
     *
     * @param string $file the filename of the template to load
     */
    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a value for replacing a specific tag.
     *
     * @param string $key the name of the tag to replace
     * @param string $value the value to replace
     */
    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this->values[$key] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the content of the template, replacing the keys for its respective values.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function output() {
        /**
         * Tries to verify if the file exists.
         * If it doesn't return with an error message.
         * Anything else loads the file contents and loops through the array replacing every key for its value.
         */
        if (!file_exists($this->file)) {
            return "Error loading template file ($this->file).<br />";
        }
        $output = file_get_contents($this->file);

        foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
            $tagToReplace = "[@$key]";
            $output = str_replace($tagToReplace, $value, $output);
        }

        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Merges the content from an array of templates and separates it with $separator.
     *
     * @param array $templates an array of Template objects to merge
     * @param string $separator the string that is used between each Template object
     * @return string
     */
    static public function merge($templates, $separator = "\n") {
        /**
         * Loops through the array concatenating the outputs from each template, separating with $separator.
         * If a type different from Template is found we provide an error message. 
         */
        $output = "";

        foreach ($templates as $template) {
            $content = (get_class($template) !== "Template")
                ? "Error, incorrect type - expected Template."
                : $template->output();
            $output .= $content . $separator;
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you are asking. Do you have any code? Maybe you add your question in german and I'll translate it?

Comment: Danke für deine Hilfe.

Comment: Now seeing the class and the mothod `set()`: This thing with `eval` and executing php code there won't work, and is a bad idea anyway. Eval is evil ("Eval" ist teuflisch). Please find another way of doing what you want to achieve. Du solltest eine andere art finden das zu erreichen was du willst. So wird es nicht gehen.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution using `ob_start`. In the `panel.php` I execute the PHP code via `eval`.

```
// Ausgabepuffer an
ob_start();
// Skript ausführen
$_GET['panel'] = 1;
include('panel.php');
// Ausgabe aus Puffer holen
$inhalt = ob_get_contents();
// Puffer schließen
ob_end_clean();

//Layout holen
$layout = new Template("template/layout.tpl");
$layout->set("title", $sitename);
$layout->set("content", $inhalt);
```

What do you think about this?

Es war keine wirkliche Lösung, wie es sich herausgestellt hat.
Versuche  nun die Template Engine von Smarty zu nutzen. Weiß jemand wie ich dort PHP im Template darstellen kann?

```
require '../libs/Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->compile_check = true;
$smarty->debugging = false;

$smarty->assign("Name","Fred Irving Johnathan Bradley Peppergill");
$smarty->assign("Menu","MENU");
$smarty->assign("Content", "echo 'Testinhalt soll angezeigt werden.'; ");


$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```